# Custom Wordpress Nav with wp_nav_menu function

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

I am struggling to get the `wp_nav_menu` function working with my custom html. I have tried looping over the items but had no success hence why I went back to the native function.

I have attached the order of the menu items in wordpress and the HTML I am trying to loop over with the values I am tying to insert in them. The duplicate pages are just so other menu sections have pages.

**Menu Order in WP**

1. What We Do(parent)

   - Sectors(child of parent)

     - Audit(child of child)
     - Component
   - Solutions

     - Blog Single
     - Case Studies
   - Products
2. Resources

   - Component
   - Case Studies
   - Blog Single
   - Blog
3. About

   - Component
   - Case Studies
   - Blog Single
4. Case Studies

**HTML for looping over**

```
          <!-- Should loop per parent  -->  
          <div class="header-dropdown w-dropdown>

            <div class="header-dropdown-toggle w-dropdown-toggle">
              <div class="dropdown-text">{parent.title}</div>
            </div>

            <nav class="mega-menu-container w-dropdown-list">
              <div class="w-layout-grid mega-menu-grid v3">

                <!-- Should loop per child of the parent  -->                
                <div class="mega-menu-column-1">
                  <h4 class="mega-menu-title">{parent.children.title}</h4>

                    <!-- Should loop per child of child  -->
                    <div class="mega-menu-links">
                      <a href="{parent.children.children.url}" class="mega-menu-link">{parent.children.children.title}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom walker function

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
'menu'   => 'any menu',
'walker' => new WPDocs_Walker_Nav_Menu()));
```

'menu' Desired menu. Accepts a menu ID, slug, name, or object.

```
/**
 * Custom walker class.
 */
class WPDocs_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
 
    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * Adds classes to the unordered list sub-menus.
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
     */
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        // Depth-dependent classes.
        $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
        $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
        $classes = array(
            'sub-menu',
            ( $display_depth % 2  ? 'menu-odd' : 'menu-even' ),
            ( $display_depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu' : '' ),
            'menu-depth-' . $display_depth
        );
        $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );
 
        // Build HTML for output.
        $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n";
    }
 
    /**
     * Start the element output.
     *
     * Adds main/sub-classes to the list items and links.
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
     * @param int    $id     Current item ID.
     */
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
 
        // Depth-dependent classes.
        $depth_classes = array(
            ( $depth == 0 ? 'main-menu-item' : 'sub-menu-item' ),
            ( $depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu-item' : '' ),
            ( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
            'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
        );
        $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );
 
        // Passed classes.
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );
 
        // Build HTML.
        $output .= $indent . '<li id="nav-menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" class="' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';
 
        // Link attributes.
        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ' class="menu-link ' . ( $depth > 0 ? 'sub-menu-link' : 'main-menu-link' ) . '"';
 
        // Build HTML output and pass through the proper filter.
        $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
            $args->before,
            $attributes,
            $args->link_before,
            apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
            $args->link_after,
            $args->after
        );
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

also, you can check this 'WP Bootstrap Navwalker'

https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker